# Transaction ID on AuthorizeAndCapture by AuthorizedotNet

Tags: c#, authorize.net

I'm trying to get the transaction ID by `AuthorizeAndCapture` method from **AuthorizeNet API**.

```
private static void CreateTransaction(long profileId, long paymentProfileId)
{
    CustomerGateway target = new CustomerGateway(ApiLogin, TransactionKey);
    var response = target.AuthorizeAndCapture(profileId.ToString(), paymentProfileId.ToString(), 1020.00M);

    Console.WriteLine("Hola" + response.TransactionID);
}
```

But, when i execute the method, the property `response.TransactionID` returns empty.

I tried to change from sandbox to production and doesn't works neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the issue using another gateway of the Authorize Net

```
private static void CreateTransaction(long profileId, long paymentProfileId)
    {
        Gateway target = new Gateway(ApiLogin, TransactionKey, true);
        Customer cust = new Customer {ProfileID = profileId.ToString()};

        IGatewayRequest request = new AuthorizationRequest("4111111111111111", "0224", 20.10M,
            "AuthCap transaction approved testing", true);
        request.AddCustomer("31358164", "bla_bla@bla.com", "", "", "street", "City",
            "State","256984");

        const string description = "AuthCap transaction approved testing";

        var actual = target.Send(request, description);
```

Into "actual" we found transactionID.

I hope to help others.